# Bash script curl return value within a script

Tags: bash, curl

I'm a stumped here.  I have a simple script that checks to see if end-point is available via curl command. It checks the return value and if the value is not '0', it exists. Here is a sample:

```
url="http://xxy.bb.cc.com:7799"
curl -Is $url > /dev/null 2&>1
retVal=$?   
[[ $retVal -ne 0 ]] &&  echo "$url is not accessible"  && exit $retVal
```

When I execute the command from within my script it returns a non-zero value but when I ran the same sequence of commands manually off my terminal (Mac OS), it works and returns 0.

Any idea why ?

Comment: I think `2&>1` should be `2>&1`

Comment: `>/dev/null 2>&1` is always a bad idea when you are first developing something. When I ran `curl -vIs $url  ; echo $?` on my command-line,  I got back some interesting IP addresses, and `7` as the return code. Is that what you expected? Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @MarcoLucidi   You are spot on, I have been starring at this for too long.  That fixed my problem.